# I want to end the while loop when user clicks cancel in the confirm box

Tags: javascript

```
        let age = Number(prompt('Enter your age'))
        if (age <= 0) {
            alert('Enter a valid age')
            console.error('Enter a valid age');
        }
        if (age < 18) {
            alert('You cannot drive')
        }
        else if (age >= 18) {
            alert('Yes you can drive')
        }

        let askAgain = confirm('Do you want to see thr prompt again?')

        while (askAgain == true) {
            let age = Number(prompt('Enter your age'))
            if (age <= 0) {
                alert('Enter a valid age')
                console.error('Enter a valid age');
            }
            else if (age >= 18) {
                alert('Yes you can drive')
            }
            if (age < 18) {
                alert('You cannot drive')
            }
            let askAgain = confirm('Do you want to see thr prompt again?')
        }
```

I want to make the confirm box go away if the user selects cancel. It works fine the first time but if I select ok first and the while loop executes and then It keeps on showing the confirm box even if I select cancel.

Comment: use labels, `loopLabel: while()... ` then break it on click `break loopLabel`

Answer (score 0):

You have declared ***askAgain*** variable twice - first outside the while loop and then again inside the loop.

Just remove the '**let**' keyword present in front of *askAgain* (which is present inside of while loop). This will fix the issue.